# Best practices for changing inputs and outputs on the fly in AudioKit?

Tags: swift, macos, audiokit

I'm wondering if there are best practices for how to switch the input of `AudioKit.setInputDevice(...)` and `mic.setDevice(...)`, as well as `AudioKit.setOutputDevice(...)` on the fly?

Should `.stop()` and `.start()` be called around such operations on `AKMicrophone`s and AudioKit itself?

Working on an app that allows users to set their desired input and output devices, I usually receive numerous errors, usually resulting in no audio being functional after that point.

Setting the same custom input / output devices from startup works reliably.

Here is a Playground for switching inputs and outputs. You should find that if you change the output on the fly, inputs no longer function and pass audio.

```
//: ## Tracking Microphone Input
//:
import AudioKitPlaygrounds
import AudioKit

let mic = AKMicrophone()
//: Set the microphone device if you need to
if let inputs = AudioKit.inputDevices {
    let inputNum = 0
    try AudioKit.setInputDevice(inputs[inputNum])
    try mic.setDevice(inputs[inputNum])
}
let silence = AKBooster(gain: 0)

AudioKit.output = silence
try AudioKit.start()

//: User Interface
import AudioKitUI

class LiveView: AKLiveViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        addTitle("Input / Output switching")
        addTitle("Inputs")


        /// Input picker
      if let inputs = AudioKit.inputDevices {
        for input in inputs {
          let newButton = AKButton(title: input.name, callback: { _ in
            do {
              print("Setting mic to \(input.name)")
              try mic.setDevice(input)
            }
            catch {
              print(error)
            }

            do{
              print("Setting audioInputDevice to \(input.name)")
              try AudioKit.setInputDevice(input)
            }catch{
              print(error)
            }

          })
          addView(newButton)
        }
      }

      let rollingPlot = AKNodeOutputPlot(mic, frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 440, height: 200))
      rollingPlot.plotType = .buffer
      rollingPlot.shouldFill = true
      rollingPlot.shouldMirror = true
      rollingPlot.color = AKColor.red
      rollingPlot.gain = 2
      addView(rollingPlot)

      addTitle("Outputs")

      // Output Picker
      if let outputs = AudioKit.outputDevices {
        for output in outputs {
          let newButton = AKButton(title: output.name, callback: { _ in
            do {
              print("Trying setOutputDevice to \(output.name)")
              try AudioKit.setOutputDevice(output)
            }
            catch {
              print(error)
            }
          })
          addView(newButton)
        }
      }
    }
}

import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = LiveView()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Give an example of a specific change you attempted and the error(s) you get.

Comment: Ideally if you could provide an example project we could run that would be best. We could even integrate it into AudioKit as an example so that others would benefit from your trailblazing.

Comment: The reason I mention the example project is because Playgrounds, for all their coolness can be flaky.